# Are small peppers inside others twins?

Tags: botany

This happens frequently enough that we've probably all seen it at some point - you buy a pepper, and when you cut it open you find another small pepper inside it. There's plenty of pictures out there if you don't know what I mean.

The other pepper obviously didn't grow from a seed; a sprouting seed would generate a plant and not a fruit.

My first guess is that it's a twin. But seeds should be the equivalent of a fertilised animal zygote, so "monzygotic twins" would be split-seeds, not fruit-inside-fruits.

The only reliable-sounding information I was able to find online is this 8 year old blog post: https://www.csmonitor.com/The-Culture/Gardening/diggin-it/2010/0401/Have-you-ever-found-a-pepper-inside-a-pepper which concludes that it's unknown what these mini-peppers are.

Is that still accurate or has anyone figured out what exactly peppers inside peppers are?